# How to change behaviour of keys in Ubuntu?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I want to change the behaviour of certain keys.

E.g. I would like the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to simulate typing "Something".

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: In what context? Everywhere? In all applications?

Comment: i want in editors like if i press keys then it type "some text". Or its good if it is done for everywhere

Comment: @muru: Yes, i want same shortcut but i didn't get answer. pls tell me how to add shortcut. and `autokey` available for ubuntu 13.10 but i am using 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for this and i installed  **AUTOKEY** feature of ubuntu.

`sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk`

I setup my string in autokey.